# Facing issue for URI on jsp page

Tags: java, jsf, oracle-adf, taglib

I have an URI on my JSP and found the tld with jar. both jsp and tld has same URI
but I am getting the following error

```
Error(3,5):  No tag library could be found with this URI. Possible causes could be that the URI is incorrect, or that there were errors during parsing of the .tld file.
```

On JSP it looks like this

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://xmlns.oracle.com/adf/faces/rich" prefix="af"%>
```

and tld its like this

```xml
<tlib-version>11.1.2.3.0</tlib-version>
<short-name>af</short-name>
<uri>http://xmlns.oracle.com/adf/faces/rich</uri>
```

Comment: Check the TLD version against your web.xml.

Comment: At least show how the URI's are in your JSP page.

Comment: Is the JAR in `/WEB-INF/lib`? Is it really a `.tld` file or is it actually a `.taglib.xml` file?

Comment: its updated..please check

Comment: Okay, it's really a `.tld` file. Is the JAR in `/WEB-INF/lib`?

Comment: yes Jar is in same path /WEB-INF/lib/OracleADF/adf-richclient-impl-11.jar

Comment: @McDowell i cheked the taglib version with my Jdeveloper version both are same

Answer (score 1):

> *yes Jar is in same path `/WEB-INF/lib/OracleADF/adf-richclient-impl-11.jar`*

This is not right. The folder `/oracleADF` doesn't belong there. You can't create subfolders in `/WEB-INF/lib` (well, technically you can, but the servletcontainer will only lookup JARs which are placed directly in `/WEB-INF/lib` folder and ignore any folders).

Fix it accordingly by placing the JAR in `/WEB-INF/lib/adf-richclient-impl-11.jar`.

If you want to organize your JARs, either look at Ant/Maven or at Eclipse's *Build Path* and *Deployment Assembly* to automatically put the JAR files which are organized elsewhere in `/WEB-INF/lib` folder of the built WAR.

Comment: thanks you are right,i will give you extra details for my application see currently i am working on migration kind of thing, my current application is in JDEV TP4 and we are using ADF R1(release 1) jar with the same directory structure now i am going migrate my application with latest JDEV 11.1.2.3.0 and i need to use R1 library with this latest JDEV not R2, i tried with R2 i am le to resolve the error, but my requirement is i need to use R1 with latest JDEV, and i am facing this error....what approch i need to follow please suggest me.. and also in IDE we can add jar from any location...

Comment: Whatever you do, in the built WAR file, the JAR should ultimately go in directly in `/WEB-INF/lib` folder, not in a subfolder of it. That's just how the Servlet specification says it.

Comment: Exactly then its under same folder :)